# Just got the laptop and it crashed

Tags: boot, crash

I recently got a Dell Inspiron 5558 and it came with Ubuntu 14.04. I'm no Linux expert, actually I can't say I'm a computer expert at all. 
I'm a student at an Engineering University and I had the option of downloading Windows 10 and a bunch of Microsoft products for free. While I was downloading the latest Windows, the computer crashed and an error appeared (kernel panic - not syncing attempted to kill init etc.). After I restarted it I got a purple screen with 3 options: Ubuntu, Advanced Options for Ubuntu and System Setup. In Advanced Options I got two options: Ubuntu with Linux generic and the same thing with safe mode in parenthesis. Every time I open the laptop this is what I got. I know I sound like a noob but what should I do?

Comment: Your story makes no sense to me. You had linux. Then you tried to install windows?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this menu because Ubuntu didn't shut down correctly.  The advanced options can occasionally be useful for troubleshooting.

Reboot.  When this screen (or something similar) shows:

[image]

If necessary, select "Ubuntu" with the arrow keys.

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.